# Присваивание примитиву примитив

Tags: java, инициализация

Допустим, есть число, которое высчитывается долгим путем, нужно создать это же число. Делал всегда такое же высчитывание для второго числа. А можно ли сделать так?

```
int second = first;
```

Я вот сомневаюсь, что при изменении `first` изменится и `second`, это не нужно.

А если так?

```
int second = 0 + first;
```

Так?

```
int second = new Integer(first);
```

Так?

```
int second = Integer.valueOf(first);
```

Помогите разобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если всё это написано в main методе, что то типа:

```
int first=100;
int second=first
// пересчитываем first
```

Как бы ты не задавал second, она не будет изменятся в будущем, потому что он запоминает определённое значение, а не ссылку на значение.
   В отличии от массива или объектной переменной:

```
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        int[] first={1};
        int[] second=first;
        first[0]++;
        System.out.println(first[0]+" "+second[0]);
    }
```

Comment: тоесть если я создам Integer вместо int то уже двум переменным будет дана ссылка на один обьект и его изменение повлияет и на второй если поменять первый?

Comment: @Flippy, Если бы `Integer` был изменяемым, то да, повлияло бы, но так как `Integer` является неизменяемым (при изменении создается новый объект), то это изменение не повлияет на старый объект.

Answer (score 2):

> А можно ли сделать так?
>
> ```
> int second = first;
> ```

Да, можно (а почему нет-то?).

> Я вот сомневаюсь, что при изменении `first` изменится и `second`, это не нужно

И правильно сомневаетесь, не изменится.

> А если так?
>
> ```
> int second = 0 + first;
> ```

И так не изменится.

> Так?
>
> ```
> int second = new Integer(first);
> ```

Так тоже не изменится. Здесь создается объект класса `Integer`, который затем автораспаковывается в `int`.

> Так?
>
> ```
> int second = Integer.valueOf(first);
> ```

В этом случае тоже не изменится.

Давайте подробнее рассмотрим последние два случая:

```
Integer a = 5;
Integer b = new Integer(5);
System.out.println(a == b);
```

Здесь на консоль будет выведено `false`, так как `a` и `b` – это два разных объекта.

В этом же случае:

```
Integer a = 5;
Integer b = Integer.valueOf(5);
System.out.println(a == b);
```

на консоль будет выведено `true`, так как метод `Integer.valueOf(...)` сначала проверит, есть ли объект со значением `5` в пуле, и, если есть, возвратит ссылку на существующий объект*, в противном случае будет создан новый объект. Так как объект со значением `5` уж есть в пуле (`a`), то метод `Integer.valueOf(...)` возвратит ссылку на него и `a == b` будет истинно.

*пул ограничивается некоторыми значениями, как правило это `[-128;127]`. Пример:

```
Integer a = 500;
Integer b = Integer.valueOf(500);
System.out.println(a == b);
```

Здесь будет выведено на консоль `false`, так как объект со значением `500` в пуле размещен не будет.

И еще один случай:

```
Integer a = 5;
Integer b = a;
a = 10;
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
```

На консоли увидите:

```
10
5
```

Так как в строке `Integer b = a;` происходит копирование ссылки и при выполнении `a = 10;` будет создан новый объект (или считан объект из пула), так как `Integer` (как и все другие объектные оболочки примитивов) является неизменяемым.

Answer (score 1):

Примитивы в Java передаются по значению, объектные типы - по ссылке.
Это означает что операция присвоения приведет к копированию значения (!) переменной примитивного типа, и к копированию ссылки на объект объектного типа.

То есть, в случае с примитивами - Вы получите две переменные имеющие одинаковые значения:

```
int a = 1;
int b = a;
b++;
System.out.println("A = " + a + " / b = " + b); // выведет "A = 1 / b = 2"
```

В случае с объектными типами - Вы получите две ссылки на один и тот же объект.

```
MyObj obj1 = new MyObj()
obj1.name = "Hello";
MyObj obj2 = obj1;
obj2.name = "world";
System.out.println("obj1.name = " + obj1.name + "// obj2.name = " + obj2.name); // выведет "obj1.name = world // obj2.name = world"
```

Подробнее информацию можно найти тут:
[http://info.javarush.ru/translation/2014/06/30/Передача-параметров-в-Java-Перевод-.html](http://info.javarush.ru/translation/2014/06/30/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-Java-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-.html)

Comment: Не путайте людей, объектные типы в Java тоже передаются по значению.